# Can I update C# console output in realtime without constantly writing to it?

Tags: c#, console

I am creating a simple fighting game console application and I have a `health` property on my `Player` objects, that is updated in the `Fight` method.

I wonder if it is possible to show the **health** variable, in real-time in the console without calling a method that updates the console more than once.

Here is my main method which starts the fight, and displays the health output of each player.

```
 public static void StartFight(Player p1, Player p2) {
   Console.Clear();
   Title(" BATTLE ");
   Console.WriteLine($"{p1.name} Health: {p1.health} ");
   Console.WriteLine($"{p2.name} Health: {p2.health} ");

   // Loop giving each player a chance to attack
   // and block each turn until 1 dies
   while (true) {
     if (Fight(p1, p2)) {
       Title(" GAME OVER! ");
       PlayAgain();
       break;
     }

     if (Fight(p2, p1)) {
       Title(" GAME OVER! ");
       PlayAgain();
       break;
     }
   }
 }
```

**Is it possible to write to the console in real-time so that I don't have to keep doing `Console.WriteLine($"{p1.name} Health: {p1.health} ");`?**

Comment: By show, do you mean displaying it in the console?

Comment: It's hard to answer without seeing your code. My suggestion would be to declare the variable before the method is called and send that variable as a parameter to the method. That way you can update and display that variable on the console.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Yes, like a Console.WriteLine($"Health: {player.health}"); and update automatically

Comment: @virouz98 I already updated the post to be more precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - if you are displaying to console, there is no way to have a realtime updating of the UI without calling a method more than once to update the console.

Other UIs have ways to do this using events, bindings etc.

Comment: Oh okay okay, so real time updating is only possible to do when we have UI like Windows Forms, WPF, Web... because of the events/bindings that they have?

Comment: Yes, correct as there is no rendering loop of any sort for you to hook onto or modify nor any events, bindings...

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much for the  quick and perceptible answer!