# Capture the time between two user entered inputs over Console Application

Tags: c#, datetime, console-application

I am trying to solve Car kata problem. I want to calculate the time between,  when user select the option to Start the car and when he decide to accelerate (considering its been done to warm engine).

On the basis of time it is idle(engine is running but not accelerated) how can I calculate the time and use that time to show the CONTINUOUS DROP in fuel level over console.

For eg:
If initially my fuel level is 20L, in idle state fuel is getting consumed at 0.002Lit/sec, then I till the time user is waiting on the screen to press Accelerate, he should see the CONTINUOUS DROP in fuel level from 20L
Assume he took 10 sec to accelerate, for every sec 0.002*1=0.002L is getting used up
for 1st sec Fuel level: 20L
for 2nd sec Fuel Level: 20L-0.002L= 19.998L and so on.

Any leads would be really helpful.
Thanks in advance

I am not asking how get time difference between two DateTime objects. I want to calculate the real time fuel consumption.

```
while(true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press 1: Start Car");
            Console.WriteLine("Press 2: Accelerate  Car");
            Console.WriteLine("Press 3: Apply Brakes Car");
            Console.WriteLine("Press 4: Stop Car");
            Console.WriteLine("Press 5: Refuel Car");
            //Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            //sw.Start();
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            
            
            switch (input)
            {
                case "1":
                    Console.WriteLine("Starting the Car...");
                    c.EngineStart();
                    
                    
                    //Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds * 1000);
                    
                    //var total = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds * 1000;
                    break;

                case "2":
                    Console.WriteLine("Accelerating...");
                    
                    break;

                default:

                    break;

            }
            //sw.Stop();
        }


 public void EngineStart()
    {
        fuel.Consume(0.0003);
        Console.WriteLine("Fuel Level " + fuel.getFuelLevel());
        Console.WriteLine("Speed " + "0 km/hr"); 
    }
```

Comment: no @ErmiyaEskandary, I think I made it clear via example. Let  me try again. What i am trying to think of is to get the real value of Fuel Tank over console. While user is waiting after igniting the engine. I want to see the continuous drop in fuel capacity value wrt time.

Comment: You can't realtime update the console https://www.stackoverflow.com/a/69425916/4800344

Answer (score 1):

You can declare two `DateTime` variables just just both the `Console.ReadLine` and assign them `DateTime.Now`. And then take difference of these two variables

Answer (score 0):

Use stopwatch to capture the time between two user entered inputs

```
var watch = new Stopwatch();
var firstInput = Console.ReadKey();        
watch.Start(); // Start time measuring

// Code between 1st and 2nd input

var secondInput = Console.ReadKey();
watch.Stop(); // Stop time measuring
```

Then you can use `Stopwatch.Elapsed` property to get measured time.

Comment: How can this method help to get CONTINUOUS  drop? I am trying to make it look like a real time thing.